# How to set a security question?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, security, lock-screens, pattern-lock, micromax-a110

Reading [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/34139/15857), I found that we can set a security question to unlock the device after 5 unsuccessful unlock attempts (clicking Next). So to set a security question, I we to Settings -> Security but couldn't find any option to set a security question. So how to set a security question?

Comment: It means, your ROM doesn't support that.